# Implementation of calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to develop the calendar application in my application so for that i need to fetch the events from the native calendar to do before that I had a doubt that how can we know how many years are there in the native calendar? how can we retrieve the data?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you see the Apple Samples: SimpleEKDemo or Birthdays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch all events from a user’s Calendar database using the EKEventStore class.
You get all events form `eventstore` just put the start date as `[NSDate distantPast]` and the end date as `[NSDate distantFuture]`

```
self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
NSPredicate *fetchCalendarEvents = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate distantPast] endDate:[NSDate distantFuture] calendars:calendarArray];

NSArray *allEvents = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchCalendarEvents];
```